# how to ouptut raw value of variable in emberjs template

Tags: ember.js

I need to output a single value in a hidden form varialbe. I tried (and am using Ember 1.2):

```
  <input type='hidden' id='album_id' value='{{{album_id}}}' />
```

but this is not giving me the raw value. How would I just output the value?

thx

Comment: Maybe you can explain why you want to do it this way. The `{{input}}` helper should be also sufficient for most cases, i think.

Comment: yeah, we have an upload form that we're outputting which just uses jquery for the upload. Let me look into the input for hidden values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work because the helper is insertin script tags into the DOM. You have two options:

**1: Use the unbound helper, which will not update if the value changes** (this does not use script tags)

```
<input type='hidden' id='album_id' value='{{{unbound album_id}}}' />
```

**2: Use the bind-attr helper, which is exactly for this use case.** This helper helps setting attributes of DOM elements:

`<input type='hidden' id='album_id' {{bind-attr value='album_id'}}` />